# wix: run exe from commonfilesfolder as custom action

Tags: wix, vsto

I'm working on an installer for a Word Template built with VS2012 an VSTO.
As part od the installer I need to run vstoinstaller which is located in Common Files Folder.
It appears that the path differs between x86 and x64, so I thought using CommonFilesFolder property is a good solution. However, when building the msi package I get an error:

```
Fehler  4   The system cannot find the file '[CommonFilesFolder]Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe'.  C:\trash\WordTemplate\WordTemplateSetup\Product.wxs 31  1   WordTemplateSetup
```

Here is a part of my wxs:

```
<Binary Id="VSTOInstaller.exe" SourceFile="[CommonFilesFolder]Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" />
```

I found a couple of samples showing differentiation in wxs preprocessing, however I need to refer to the correct directory at runtime.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to run another "installer" application from the main installation package (MSI), even if it turns out to be technically possible. The right way is to author a bootstrapper (see Burn if we talk about WiX), design the payloads and prerequisites.

Comment: Good Point. Actually this is already part of a bootstrapper. But there I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it:

```
    <?define VstoInstaller="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe"?>
<CustomAction Id="RunWordVstoInstall"
              Execute="immediate"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              Return="asyncWait"
              ExeCommand="$(var.VstoInstaller) /i [INSTALLLOCATION]\WordTemplateInstaller.vsto" 
              />
<CustomAction Id="RunWordVstoUninstall"
              Execute="immediate"
              Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              Return="asyncWait"
              ExeCommand="$(var.VstoInstaller)  /u [INSTALLLOCATION]\WordTemplateInstaller.vsto" 
              />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunWordVstoUninstall" After="CostFinalize"><![CDATA[(&WordTemplateFeature <> 3)]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="RunWordVstoInstall" After="CustomizeVsto"><![CDATA[(&WordTemplateFeature = 3)]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Using a "fake" DIRECTORY in CustomAction entry together with a variable did the trick. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

The source path (SourceFile attribute value) is resolved in build-time, while MSI variable value [CommonFilesFolder] is resolved in run-time.

Use WIX variables, like $(var.Variable), to get the path on the build machine. See [Using Environment Variables in WiX](http://manfredlange.blogspot.ru/2010/02/using-environment-variables-in-wix.html).

I did not quite catch the method you want to use this, though. If this code line (`<Binary>` element) is from install package, you will not be able to run one installer inside another. If this line is from Burn bundle, then why aren't you using `<ExePackage>` element?